# The array of String property in a managed object constantly nil

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

First, I'm extracting the content from the text fields into a dictionary:

```swift
var dict: [String: String] = [:]
for metricPair in metricStackView.arrangedSubviews {
    if metricPair.subviews[0] is UITextField {
        let unitTextField = metricPair.subviews[0] as! UITextField
        let valueTextField = metricPair.subviews[1] as! UITextField
        
        if let textContent = unitTextField.text, let valueTextContent = valueTextField.text {
            let trimmedKey = textContent.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines)
            let trimmedValue = valueTextContent.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines)
            dict.updateValue(trimmedValue, forKey: trimmedKey)
        }
    }
}
```

And I'm saving it to Core Data:

```swift
let goal = Goal(context: self.context)
goal.date = Date()
 
for item in dict {
 goal.metrics?.append(item.key)
}
 
goal.progress.insert(progress)
```

My managed object looks like this:

```swift
extension Goal {
    @nonobjc public class func createFetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest<Goal> {
        return NSFetchRequest<Goal>(entityName: "Goal")
    }

    @NSManaged public var date: Date
    @NSManaged public var metrics: [String]?
    @NSManaged public var progress: Set<Progress>
}
```

I keep getting `nil` for the `metrics` property of `[String]` type even before the context is saved. When I log `item.key` in:

```swift
for item in dict {
 goal.metrics?.append(item.key)
}
```

the content is showing up properly.

Comment: Do you initialize metrics anywhere? What is dict.subviews?

Comment: Sorry that was a typo mistake when I was copying over my code. The issue still remains.

Comment: @Kevvv If you are not initializing `metris` array, calling `goal.metrics?.append(item.key)` will have no effect. `metrics` will always be nil.

Comment: Can you tell me an example of how to initialize it? I'm not sure why the code below `goal.progress.insert(progress)` works without initializing it then, even though the `progress` property is Set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can tell from the above code, `metrics` array is not initialized.

Try replacing this line:

```
goal.metrics?.append(item.key)
```

With these lines:

```
if case nil = goal.metrics?.append(item.key) {
    goal.metrics = [item.key]
}
```

or with simply these lines:

```
if goal.metrics == nil {
    goal.metrics = []
}
goal.metrics?.append(item.key)
```

Comment: Could you explain this line please `if case nil = goal.metrics?.append(item.key) {`

Comment: This is pattern matching. Whenever the right part of the `=` (`goal.metrics?.append(item.key)`) produces `nil` (in this case when array not initialized) then the inside line will be called. Create a new array with the specified one element. https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/ReferenceManual/Patterns.html

Comment: I'm getting the `Cannot convert value of type '[String]' to expected element type 'Array<String>.ArrayLiteralElement' (aka 'String')` error for `goal.metrics = [item.key]` in the second example you provided

Comment: @Kevvv the first one works OK and the second one doesn't? I am surprised because both do the exact same thing.

Comment: Yes. I just initialized it with `goal.metrics = []` and added `goal.metrics = item.key` and it works.

Comment: @Kevvv that's weird. I updated my answer with the working code.